On covering countable numbers
Let $x_k=\frac{k}{n}$，$I_k=[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{n})$, $l()$ is the Lebesgue measure, then
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} l\left(\bigcup_k I_k\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_k l(I_k)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\frac{1}{n}=1
\end{equation}
Let $x_k=\frac{k}{n}$，$I'_k=[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})$
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} l\left(\bigcup_k I'_k\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_k l(I'_k)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\frac{1}{n^2}=0
\end{equation}
Besides, as $n\rightarrow \infty$ any interval in the form of $[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})$ contains an interval in the form of $[\frac{k'}{m},\frac{k'}{m}+\frac{1}{m}),k'=\frac{mk}{n},m=n^2+1$, vise versa.
In both of the above cases, $x_k$ is covered by an infinitesimal interval, but the total lengths are different. Does this mean that the Lebesgue measure is not uniquely determined?

What makes you think the measure of the limit is the limit of the measures? Moreover, there is neither $x_k$ per se (since it depends on $n$) nor something like an "infinitesimal interval".

The same derivation appeared in the main-stream textbooks of real analysis but only for the second case, and to my knowledge, it was one of the starting points of Borel and Lebesgue's measure theory:  if an arbitrarily small interval is used to cover each point of a countable number of points, the cover's total length (initially termed the outer content) diminishes.  I assume this is provable and then constructed a seemly larger interval. Yet this larger interval is at the same time smaller than the smaller one.

The first issue here on the nose is that you're not covering countably many stationary points: As I noted already, you $x_k$ depend on $n$, and in particular in the limit they all equal 0, and are therefore not even contained in, say $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_k I_k$.

Moreover, there are generally conditions on when you can interchange limits of measurable sets (in particular, intervals) and $l$. For instance, you can do this when your sequence of sets is descending and of finite measure (which I assume is generally the case for the textbook example you cite). There is really no reason to believe your calculation shows anything unless you can rigorously further justify why your equations calculate $l(\lim_{n \to \infty}(\ldots))$.

Does this stationarity make a difference in the sum? And I'd not consider the length as 0, but it is "as small as you want", and the interval is semi-open by definition, then it contains at least a point.

Regarding the limit, normally it is done by countable additivity and they apply limit on both sides of the equality.

The length, or measure, of something is a number. "As small as you want" is not. That the intervals all contain a point does not mean their limit (or limsup, or liminf, perhaps) does so, too. Non-stationarity doesn't help make the problem clearer, at least. As for the second comment: sure, they apply countable additivity to compute the measure of a countable disjoint union of open intervals, as do you (well, half-open here) $l(\bigcup_k I_k) = \sum_k l(I_k)$. That's fine, but does not help with the other limit.

I like your understanding of infinitesimal which I referred to as "as small as you want". The point is here it does not become 0. I'd rather argue on this under this question. I'd discuss it in a separate question.

I think you'd do better with this example by letting $x_k = k$, $I_k = [k, k + 1 / n)$, and $J_k = [k, k + 1 / n^2)$ so that you actually have stationary points and nested intervals that converge to something non-empty; the mutually nested intervals part is still true and your calculations remain the same, just to make things simpler.
